# Simple built-in function to split number to bins

Tags: python, numpy

Im looking for a simple functuion (maybe `numpy` or any other package) that will split a given number to bins, for example:

```
func(start=0,end=100,bins=4)
```

The wanted result is:

```
(0,25,50,75,100)
```

And also for a float:

For example

```
func(start=0,end=100,bins=6)
```

The wanted result is:

```
(0,17,34,50,67,84,100)
```

Comment: Maybe `np.linspace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import numpy as np


def fun(start=0, end=0, bins=4):
    return tuple(np.ceil(np.linspace(start=start, stop=end, num=bins + 1)).astype(np.int32))


print(fun(start=0, end=100, bins=4))
print(fun(start=0, end=100, bins=6))
```

**Output**

```
(0, 25, 50, 75, 100)
(0, 17, 34, 50, 67, 84, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this without numpy, you can figure out the gap with by dividing `(ends - start) / bins`, then use a range over the number of bins (+1) and round accordingly.

```
import math

def f(start, end, bins):
    gap = (end - start) / bins
    return tuple(math.ceil(n * gap + start) for n in range(bins + 1))
    
f(start=0,end=100,bins=4)
# (0, 25, 50, 75, 100)

f(start=0,end=100,bins=6)
# (0, 17, 34, 50, 67, 84, 100)

f(start=10,end=50,bins=6)
# (10, 17, 24, 30, 37, 44, 50)
```